# Importange not updating data on a cell for over a month, but updating other cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem with a Google sheet that imports from another sheet, it's only partially updating, all values from previous months are getting imported, and updated if modified, but the values for February, which had an error at some point in the source sheet, are not getting updated, stuck on importing the values for February as they were at that time there was an error.

This is how it looks like on the sheet with the importrange:
[image: This is the error on the import sheet]
I have to point out that the error was solved Feb 1st, so it's importing a cell that's been edited 20 days ago today.

This is another import formula in the sheet:
[image: Formula]
This is how the range looks in the import sheet:
[image: Result of the formula on import sheet]
This is how the range is in the source sheet:
[image: Imported range on source sheet]

I've re-written the formulas, changed the ranges imported so they're not for the whole column, removed the = sign and rewriting it (which has worked for me in other sheets), set both sheets update interval to every minute and when's changes, deleted and pasting the link again.

I feel like I've tried as much as I can to fix this, but to no avail. Does anybody know why this happens/how to fix it.

Comment: It is very hard to troubleshoot this problem without access to the sheet. It may be problem with range sizes. We even don't know what exactly error is behind REF! message (there could be many).

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski There is no message behind the error, it's plain text that's being "imported" from the source sheet. The error existed in the source sheet in the cells that say error, but that was 20 days ago and doesn't anymore, now it has numbers. Unfortunately I can't provide the link because the document is confidential (and in an enclosed workspace), and can't replicate the error on another sheet.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to figure this out blindly without a sample. Is it always the same row that has the error? Are the source cells protected by any chance? If they're protected it's possible that could be the cause.

Comment: @Daniel Source isn't protected. it's all of the February row. The source sheet had an error for February, so all the row had error for a day. The import sheet synchronized at that time, then source sheet was fixed but import sheet never changed the fixed cells.

Comment: @heliospaniagua Try this then. Create a brand new spreadsheet. Re-create all data and formulas (do **not** just copy the formulas). See if it works. If it does and do have to keep the original sheet, mirror everything from the new sheet to the old one using a new `IMPORTRANGE`. If you don't need the old sheet just use the new one.